# Determine type of existing socket handle under Linux

Tags: linux, sockets

Given only an existing/open socket handle, how can I determine whether the socket is a connection-oriented socket under Linux? I am searching for something like the `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` under Windows, which I can retrieve using `getsockopt`.

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int sock_type;
socklen_t sock_type_length = sizeof(sock_type);
getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &sock_type, &sock_type_length);

if (sock_type == SOCK_STREAM) {
    // it's TCP or SCTP - both of which are connection oriented
} else if (sock_type == SOCK_DGRAM) {
    // it's UDP - not connection oriented
}
```

I suppose this is slightly simplistic, as there can be other protocols that can be stream or datagram, but this code is almost always what you want.

Comment: SOCK_STREAM can be associated to TCP and SCTP, thus this solution is wrong.

Comment: @OttavioCampana Excuse me?  The question is about whether it's connection-oriented or not.  SCTP is connection oriented, so I think the solution is probably fine.  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.commadmn%2Fdoc%2Fcommadmndita%2Fsctp_intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket):

> **Socket options**
>
> These socket options can be set by using setsockopt(2) and read with
>   getsockopt(2) with the socket level set to SOL_SOCKET for all sockets:
>
> ...
>
> **SO_PROTOCOL** (since Linux 2.6.32)
>       Retrieves the socket protocol as an integer, returning a value such as IPPROTO_SCTP. See socket(2) for details. This socket option is
>   read-only.
>
> **SO_TYPE**
>      Gets the socket type as an integer (e.g., SOCK_STREAM). This socket option is read-only.

To correct the solution provided by xaxxon, the code has to be:

```
int sock_type;
socklen_t sock_type_length = sizeof(sock_type);
getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &sock_type, &sock_type_length);

if (sock_type == SOCK_STREAM) {
    getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PROTOCOL, &sock_type, &sock_type_length);
    if (sock_type == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        // it's TCP
    } else {
        // it's SCTP
    }
} else if (sock_type == SOCK_DGRAM) {
    // it's UDP
}
```

Comment: I think the list of values SO_PROTOCOL returns is [here](http://linux.die.net/include/netinet/in.h)

Comment: SO_PROTOCOL can have IPPROTO_TCP and IPPROTO_UDP, which is more precise that the solution provided by xaxxon, because SOCK_STREAM can also refer to SCTP sockets. You che check it here http://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp

Comment: If you know you're not using sctp, then you're going to be fine.  The default SOCK_STREAM protocol is TCP. Also, the question was whether or not the socket is connection-oriented or not -- none of these answers REALLY answer that.